# SDL Tridion Content Porter to Merge Content

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I would like to use content porter to move content from environment A to environment B.  If component xyz is in both environment A and environment B, is there any way to prevent component xyz from updating if the last modified date in environment B is more recent than environment A? If not, any other ideas how to solve for this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Check the mapping.xml tag < URIReplacements >. You can provide different source and Destination URI/WebDav locations. I have not tried for the exclude but replacement.

You need to build logic for the LastModified Date on source & destination. This could be bit tricky( there are ways to do this using Triggers )

Thanks
Vin

Answer (score 0):

If you know which components you need to protect, simply check them out on the target system. As long as Content Porter is run with a different account than the one which holds the checkout, the item will not be updated.